# PlayWright does not find the Element

Tags: python, html, dom, automation, playwright-python

I'm having a problem and I need help.

The page I want to automate has two HTML tags, one inside the other (that is, "two pages" in one) and it seems that PlayWright does not recognize the elements that belong to the second HTML tag (which is inside the first). Does anyone know how to solve this problem? Or do you have any tool tips that I can use to do the automation?

[ERROR after code execution][Page HTML](https://i.stack.imgur.com/R715u.jpg)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yV5M0.jpg)

I've already tried changing the type of selector, and also extending the TimeOut time so that the page loads completely, but I was unsuccessful in selecting the element.

Comment: It's very hard to help without a [mcve] of the code you wrote, the page you're automating and a description of what you're trying to accomplish. Please see [Why should I not upload images of code/data/errors?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-should-i-not-upload-images-of-code-data-errors). Your second "page inside a page" is probably an iframe, and there are [many existing resources for selecting elements in iframes in Playwright](https://playwright.dev/python/docs/frames).